# I workout everyday. Weightlifting in the morning and crossfit after work and I never take a rest day

Tags: weightlifting, recovery, abdominals, overtraining

I don't ever feel sore though. I'm afraid that I'm not seeing the gains and muscle definition I want too because of these training style. I should have abs, but don't see them.  And before anyone says diet, I'm a vegan who eats whole foods and barely ever anything processed.  Any advice?

Comment: Vegan or not, abs are about definition, and definition comes from reducing body fat percentage. Have you seen any fluctuations in your body weight?

Comment: In my opinion, you're over training.  Training more is not necessarily better.  you need to give yourself time to recover.

Comment: Is your question how to increase your ab definition? How long have you been doing your training?

Comment: When someone says you need to diet to see abs he doesn't only mean you have to eat healthy. Eat less than you need. Doesn't matter if you eat healthy. You need to reduce body fat percentage to see abs. You could get abs eating junk food every day. Abs aren't about eating healthy.

Comment: thanks gus.  I have gained weight since training.  I used to be under 100 pounds and never saw abs either.  I lift heavy and do all the compound movements and don't waste time with silly ab exercises either.  I've done my research which is why i'm so frustrated.  I know I have to eat less, and I usually don't eat enough for my training...

Comment: Just to get this clear, what is the question? Is it about not getting sore after a training or is it about wanting to see your abs?

Comment: "don't waste time with silly ab exercises either" vs "I should have abs, but don't see them" if you want a muscle to grow and develop, directly train it.

Comment: I just put I don't get sore to show that i'm not pushing my body when it isn't ready.  The question is about abs. I am just very confused.  Most people would assume by how hard I work and the effort I put in and the way I eat, that abs would be a no brainer, but maybe its my genetics?

Comment: JJsaur I know I need to train abs, but I'm not spending hours doing crunches etc.  I do all the compound moves daily with some abs thrown in; from my research this should be the best way; not directly training them for a session.

Comment: Can you please try switching timing of your workout, basically crossfit in morning and weights post work? Mostly body gets adapted to a particular circadian rhythm if on daily routine.

Answer (score 1):

**To gain muscle you need progressive overload. By the looks of it you train very intense, but in a different way.**

If you want to gain muscle, you should train a bit less, I'd say 4 to 5 days a week, and go heavier on your lifts. You should try a 5x5 program on your compound lifts, this is highly effective. **Resting periods and a proper diet are as important if not more than the lifting itself,** keep this in mind.

You say you're vegan, which is great! But you need to make sure you are getting enough nutrients to gain muscle, if you're eating 2000 calories a day but also burn that much, your body doesn't have anything to build muscle from. I would suggest a lot of lentils, beans, chickpeas, broccoli, that kind of foods.

Also, abs are made in the kitchen, as stated before. As for building the actual muscle, my opinion is that heavy compound lifts like squats or deadlifts are more beneficial than doing an endless amount of crunches or leg raises.

Comment: I'm going to second this. I think your program may be a little too much for your diet. Vegetarian and especially vegan diets take more work in terms of getting enough protein, but it can be done. Peas, lentils, beans, and various nuts are a good source of protein for vegans, but you need to be eating enough.

Comment: thanks for the tips and advice guys.  I guess a lot of it is psychological for me and I know I should rest.  I go about as heavy as I can and I've found that 5x5 isn't challenging enough for me.  I prefer doing a little bit of a variation with volume and weight.  I eat very well so that doesn't seem to be my concern, but I totally agree with both of you that more calories is important.  I just still get confounded about my abs, even though I recently learned I have very tight hip flexors and an anterior pelvic tilt so any ab work I attempt to do is fruitless : (

Comment: @marisa How come you find 5x5 not challenging enough? If this is the case, you probably aren't going heavy enough on them. If you can do more than 5 reps per set, you aren't going heavy enough :)

Comment: I mean I guess challenging is the wrong word; boring maybe?  My body is very good at adapting and I find that I need change and different rep schemes.  I swear sometimes I think I should get studied or genetic testing done because I do not fit any fitness or exercise science paradigms!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a week off from all training. Come back the following week with a written workout plan that is progressive in weight and intensity.

Answer (score -1):

Generally you'll have to put in enough intensity, volume, and time-under-tension to feel sore the next day. If you're just going light on these, then that's just a lightweight workout you can do everyday.

Lots of people go out on a walk and/or a short run on a daily basis too -- it just depends on how hard your workout *actually* is!

Comment: My work outs are very intense lol and I am constantly walking with my job and I run 5 miles about 2x a week... I think I might just be one of the genetically unlucky ones

Comment: But how much weight you actually lift on the crossfit exercises? Intensity is a *very* relative/subjective measure --- but actual amount of weight is a lot more objective. Do you deadlift 100 reps of 400 lbs every day? Also -- my coworker runs 7 miles a day in the morning before work, 5 days a week! No issues on his side, either!

Comment: Anyone who has seen me workout knows I'm intense. And I lift as heavy as I can for a 5'3 petite female.  And what do you mean about your coworker?  No issues? As in not sore everyday or he also is genetically unlucky?

Comment: Well, since you clearly do not want to publish any hard numbers here (and your whole workout in general), then this seems to be a very self-conscious issue for you. So, don't get mad if I suggest that your perceptions of the intensity and difficulty of your workout may well be quite over-exaggerated!

Comment: I wasn't mad! I mean I'm not a beast, but I my 1RM squat is 170, my DL is 245, Bench (pretty sad, but working on it) 115.

Comment: So, does that mean you only do one rep a day? ; ) What are your sets & reps on those (and other) exercises like?

Comment: I am currently following DUP training style so each day is different and works on strength, power and endurance.  So the reps and sets vary depending on what I'm working.  And of course I'm not doing 1 rep per day...

Comment: I took a brief look at DUP and it seems they put a lot of emphasis on sets and reps (ie "volume"), which, to me, actually sounds rather restrictive/incomplete. There's little to no mention of "overall" time-under-tension (TUT), which, though often ignored, can actually be almost, if not equally, as important of a component in any strength-building workout. While I'm not sure how this would fit into your DUP program, I'd highly recommend trying out some timed sets, shooting for a total of 10+ minutes under tension over all the sets of a single exercise.

Comment: You'll generally need some timer to accurately record your sets' start/stop times and sum them up to get the overall TUT for a given exercise. Note -- TUT training is generally meant to complement a volume & frequency driven workout, not completely replace it! : )

Comment: "soreness" is a bad flag for amount of effort put into something. How you feel afterwards (rate of perceived exhaustion) is a better measure.